# Formula relative to cell calling the formula in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm using Excel XP.
My problem is that I wrote a very short function ti simplify one task.

The code is the following:

```
Function getLastValue() as Integer
  getLastValue = ActiveCell.End(xltoLeft).Value
End Function
```

Then I want to fill by dragging that cell downwards, but the same value will be copied, no matter what value appears in each row. So I wanted to make it relative to the cell calling the function so that it goes to the nearest cell in the left that has a value and copy return it in the cell calling the function.

I made a Sub for it but I want to have it in the form of a function to apply it on arbitrary cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Application.Caller` is what you want.
You will also need `Application.Volatile` in order to update the formula when your worksheet changes.

---

```
Function getLastValue() As Integer
  Application.Volatile
  getLastValue = Application.Caller.End(xlToLeft).Value
End Function
```